# In a one-to-one relationship, where should the foreign key be placed?

Tags: database-design, table, erd

I am currently designing an ERD for a project management system. I am unable to choose between two workable solutions as the best solution as I wish to embrace the best standards.

The two entities that can access the system are the clients and employees. Since they have different information, I decided to treat them as different entities. I figured that it is best to have a single table for users of the system rather having the username and password fields be found in both tables of clients and employees. Plus, the constraints I have to follow:

- All users are only limited to employees and clients.
- But not all employees are required to be users of the system.

Here are the following entities without relationship yet defined:

[image: Entities]

Now, there is only one-to-one relationship between users and clients, employees and users. My question is where should I place the foreign key? Should I place two foreign keys in users table namely employee_id and client_id which makes it easier to find the associated client and employee entity from the user entity and where I can define authorization rules more easily? Or should I place each foreign key on clients and employees referencing the users table since I am unsure if it is an acceptable practice to have two foreign keys in a table in which only one foreign key can be used at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me just say (as others have pointed out), that there is **nothing** wrong with having mutually-exclusive foreign keys!

Second, despite it's elegance and applicability to *other* scenarios, I don't think the [superset solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128506/in-a-one-to-one-relationship-where-should-the-foreign-key-be-placed#128514) posted by [@Joel Brown](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3106/joel-brown) is appropriate for your **exact** case.
Although it makes it *much* easier to deal with sub-types of 'people' (entities, users, what-have-you), it doesn't sound like your project will ever expand beyond those two groups.

---

As I see it, there are three techniques you can employ here:

1. The sub-type/superset solution, as [pointed out](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128506/in-a-one-to-one-relationship-where-should-the-foreign-key-be-placed#128514) by [@Joel Brown](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3106/joel-brown).
2. Using the three tables you currently have, with either two FK's in `users`, or an FK in each of the `Clients` and `employees` tables.
3. Having a `Role` and `user_role` table, to employ *user roles* from the `users` table (and then demoting 'client' and 'employee' to roles).

Each of these options (as you might imagine) has it's own strengths and weaknesses.

---

### Supersets:

**Pros**

- Allows you to add *any* number of "types", each of which can have as many different fields as it needs.
- Permits one 'user' to be **both** a customer and an employee (or any other sub-type) simultaneously.

**Cons**

- Does not (*inherently*) permit any sort of exclusivity between the sub-types.  *i.e.* if we have sub-types 'Cop' and 'robber', one entity can be both a Cop and a Robber at the same time.
- Therefore (as you mentioned in your comments), makes it difficult to determine what *type* a particular person/entity **is**.
- Does not allow there to be an employee whom is not also an 'entity' (or person, or what-ever name you give the master table).  (although, I should point out , does allow an employee whom is not a *user*.)

### Current Design

**Pros**

- Allows each of your "types" (`Clients` and `employees`) to have as many different fields as it needs.
- Permits exclusivity between types, *i.e.* one user cannot have a `user_type` that is simultaneously `Client` *and* `user`.
- Allows there to be an employee whom is **not** also a user.

**Cons**

- Will not scale to more than a handful of "types".  *i.e.* if you had more than just `Clients` and `employees`, but 20+ types - queries on this would get *very* slow (as each type needs a new FK in users).
- Does not *implicitly* allow you to determine what 'type' a `user` is **easily** (assuming you stay with FK in `users`, PK would inverse this).

### User Roles

**Pros**

- Can scale to thousands (or milions?) of *roles* (as roles are a much simpler construct, not requiring their own table each).

**Cons**

- Would **not** allow each *role* to have as many different fields as it needs.  (Roles would all have the same fields, most likely nothing more than a name - everything would be in application logic to decide *what* a role means.)
- Does not permit any sort of exclusivity between roles.  (You can be a Cop and a Robber at the same time again.)

---

**So what's the answer?**

Well, Roles allow massive amounts of *scalability*, but this comes at the cost of modelable complexity.  Due to their simplicity, you can have a thousand roles, but each role will tell you very little (since a role cannot have fields of it's own).  Therefore, I would say **roles are inappropriate for your project**, as you need to model *different* things for employees versus users.

Sub-types (a.k.a. superset) ***might*** work for your project.  However, the added difficulty in querying to determine a users type probably isn't worth the benefit for a system that will only ever have two types.  Additionally, the case of an employee *also* being a customer would probably **never** happen.  It would be pretty safe to assume someone working internally *and* for a customer (if such a thing were even permitted by all involved), would have a separate email/logon/identity/username for each of their *roles* (positions) and hence would just login on the appropriate account.

**Your current design** (with the double FK in `users`) both permits the modelling of the fields you need for each different *type*, **and** allows you to have the (desirable?) mutual exclusivity to prevent a user from being both a customer and an employee.  It does however maintain the issue that it is difficult to know (from just a `users` `id`) *which* table to query for that user (*i.e.* is the user a customer or employee).

To solve that problem (if you particularly care), I would suggest **adding a field to `users` to signify the type**.  This could literally be something like `user_kind`, with an `enum(client,employee)` type.  If you want to get even fancier, you could extract both that field and `user_type` to a fourth table, which has an FK back to `users` and the same dual-FK (on `user_type`) to `Clients` and `employees`.

Comment: Supersets cons: *"Does not (inherently) permit any sort of exclusivity between the sub-types. i.e. if we have sub-types 'Cop' and 'robber', one entity can be both a Cop and a Robber at the same time."* That really depends on how supersets/subsets are implemented.

Comment: Clarifications: in the superset solution, do all the foreign keys reside in the entity table? If it is so, then isn't it the same as the current design? Or is the significance difference is, every sub types should have a corresponding entry in the entity table, while the latter solution permits no entry in the users table with an entry to the employees.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ True, it does.  That is what I had meant to be getting at when I said "(_inherently_)", since you can obviously impose further constraints upon the superset to do **lots** of things - one of which would be some form of mutual exclusion.  However, the explanation in Joel Brown's [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128506/in-a-one-to-one-relationship-where-should-the-foreign-key-be-placed/128528#128514) _specifically_ (see paragraphs 3-4 of that answer) went to the case where "_an employee also happens to be a customer_" (for which the superset is most appropriate).

Comment: @Xegara The difference is the corresponding entries, yes.  In the current solution, an `employee` does not **need** to _also_ be a `User`.  However, in the [superset solution](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128506/in-a-one-to-one-relationship-where-should-the-foreign-key-be-placed/128528#128514), (as [Joel Brown](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3106/joel-brown) stated:) "_then **every** employee is one of these, as is every customer, and also therefore every user._"

Comment: So do all foreign keys reside in the superset entity?

Comment: @Xegara As per [the diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8PyoE.jpg) from [@](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3106/joel-brown)[Joel Brown](http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3106/joel-brown)'s [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128506/in-a-one-to-one-relationship-where-should-the-foreign-key-be-placed/128528#128514), **and** as he stated in a comment on [his answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128506/in-a-one-to-one-relationship-where-should-the-foreign-key-be-placed/128528#128514): "_The keys are in the children_".  Each child has an (non null) FK back to the superset.

Answer (score 1):

It is acceptable to have mutually exclusive attributes in a table.  If you only have one pair of such attributes, this may be the most practical solution.

However, some people may look at your situation as a sub-typing issue.  In this view, you are missing the superset entity.  You have a collection of *(something)*, some of which are *employees* and some of which are *customers* and some of which are also *users*.

Have you also considered what happens if an employee also happens to be a customer?  Is that important to your system or is that something that would be considered coincidental?

If you think its important to treat all *users* as a feature of one type of thing, then you need to implement the *(something)* which is currently missing from your table definitions.

Consider the following ERD:

[image: ERD]

If you supply the missing superset entity, then **every** *employee* is one of these, as is every *customer*, and also therefore every *user*.  The hard part of this is coming up with a reasonable name for this superset, but it solves the issue of having to figure out which foreign key to follow from *user*.  It also makes a connection between *employee* and *customer* should one happen to exist, and should that connection be of interest.

Comment: By doing so, then would there still be mutually exclusive key pair of 
{employee, user} and {customer, user} in the superset entity?

Comment: @Xegara The keys are in the children (employee, user, customer) so there are no nullable foreign keys.  There will still be cases where some of these relationships exist and sometimes they don't.  That's the reality of your business rules.  There's a difference, however between having two mutually exclusive foreign keys in one table and having multiple optional relationships to a single parent.

Comment: I"m sorry. I don't quite get the superset solution. Given that ERD, how will I determine if the user of the system is an employee or a client?

Comment: @Xegara - you would outer join _Entity_ to both _Employee_ and _Customer_ and see which one is not Null (or which ones, if it is possible to be both).  Keep in mind, I didn't say you have to or even should use the superset approach.  There's nothing especially wrong with two mutually exclusive foreign keys, if it doesn't bother you and if it more or less stops there.  The benefit of the superset approach is that it is more aesthetically appealing to some people and it is more appropriate if you have multiple additional attributes that are shared between the subtypes (customers and employees).

Comment: Given the OP's description I think `users` *is* the superset and `clients` and `employees` the subsets.

Comment: @MichaelGreen - It seems logical at first, but if you read OP's question you see this specifically: `•But not all employees are required to be users of the system` - So _USER_ is not the supertype because some _EMPLOYEES_ are not users.

Comment: I agree with Joel. "Persons" (or some other name) looks like the superset. users, clients and employees look like subsets.

Comment: I read that as "there will be people on the payroll who will not be represented in this application."

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to view your case as two problems, rather than one.  The first problem is a class-subclass (or, if you prefer, type-subtype) problem.  Employees and Clients are clearly subclasses of some superclass that you have left unnamed.  I'll call them Persons.  (See the [subtypes](/questions/tagged/subtypes) tag).

The second problem is the one-to-one relationship between Persons and Users.  If you just had a Persons table, then the question of which way the foreign keys should go is driven by the fact that the relationship is mandatory at one end, but optional at the other end.  If you put PersonID in the Users table, you won't have to use any NULLs here.  Every user is a person.

Now back to the first problem, the class-subclass problem.  For reasons that seem to make sense, you've chosen to have two separate tables, one for Employees and one for Clients.  If you add the Persons table, as I've suggested, you may find it convenient to store some common attributes, like name and phone number, in the Persons table instead of in both of the subclass tables.

This technique has a name:  it's called "class table inheritance" in the literature.  You can search for it on the web, or over in SO.

There is a second technique, called "shared primary key" that can be useful in cases like this one.  Using shared primary key,   the Employees table and the Clients table do not have an independent ID field.  Instead,  the PersonID field is declared as the primary key to the Employees or Clients table, in addition to its role as an FK referencing the Persons table. This technique is common when implementing IS-A relationships.

This involves a little extra programming when you insert a new Employee or Client, but it may well be worth it.

Now, you can join the users table to the Persons table, or the Employees table, or the Clients table, as the situation requires.  Only the category of users you want will appear in the joint result.

Answer (score 0):

I've only quickly looked at this but my first thought is to utilise NULL attributes in your Users table for EmployeeId and ClientId. They can then be populated as required and defined as Foreign Keys.

UserName is the Primary Key for the Users table.

Use the UNIQUE attribute on the EmployeeId, ClientId and the composite EmployeeId+ClientId within the Users table.

This would address the "Employee is also a Client" issue in the Users table.